# Conditionals in Thymeleaf

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have this piece of code in my Thymeleaf template

```
<INPUT TYPE="text" TH:VALUE="${searchForm.male}" />
<span th:if="${searchForm.male == 'true' }">
   IS TRUE
</span>
<span th:unless="${searchForm.male == 'true'}">
   IS NOT TRUE
</span>
```

but this is what I see :

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the male property is boolean just remove the quotes as follows

```
<input type="text" th:value="${searchForm.male}"/>
<span th:if="${searchForm.male == true }">IS TRUE</span>
<span th:unless="${searchForm.male == true}">IS NOT TRUE</span>
```